# jQuery not working at all in IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I written some stuff using jQuery and it works great in Chrome. When I tried to open in in IE it looked like jQuery wasn't loaded at all... Now I tried the simplest possible jQuery demo and it still doesn't work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(e){
            (e.preventDefault();
            $(this).hide("slow").show("fast");
        });   
    });


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page should hide, then show the link but it just link to the jQuery website when I open it in IE. It works normally in Chrome....

Comment: So what exactly is happening? It isn't hiding?

Comment: In theory, it will be doing nothing due to it being in quirks mode. When IE is in this state it does not allow you to set the properties of an element, thus, jQuery can not animate.

Comment: It isn't hiding... it looks like there is no jQuery at all... The link works normally.... takes me to the jQuery website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove extra ( you have written before `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

`event` is a keyword in IE, try changing that parameter to simply `e` or `evt`.

Edit: Saying that, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamiec/d8tZ9/) is working fine for me in FF, Chrome and IE.

Comment: @rusbi - are you sure you have `jquery-1.4.2.js` in the same directory as your test html file?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a doctype such as this to the top of the page. jQuery will not work when the browser is in quirks mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in code... and extra `(`.
It seems that this didn't bother Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this...

```
$(this).hide("slow").show("fast");
```

with this...

```
$(this).hide("slow", function () {
    $(this).show("fast")
});
```

I've not tested this by the way.

Comment: This makes no sense, the two are basically equivalent.